# Why does OpenZeppelin import interfaces to its own contracts?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, import, inheritance

I've noticed that all OpenZeppelin's token contracts import their interfaces into them.

1. Why does OpenZeppelin import and inherit its own contract interface to the contract?
2. Does importing a contract's interface increase the gas cost to deploy?
3. If I want to call another smart contract, like an ERC20, would it be cheaper to import the ERC20 contract with its interface? Or just importing its interface?

```js
import "./IERC20.sol";

contract A {
  IERC20 token = IERC20(address);
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Or:

import "./ERC20.sol" // <- This contract inherits the IERC20 interface

contract B {
  ERC20 token = ERC20(address);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **Inheriting** vs **Importing** another contract.

Import

```
 import "./IERC20.sol";
    
    contract A {
      IERC20 token = IERC20(address);
    }
```

Inheritance

```
import "./IERC20.sol";

contract A is IERC20 {
  //Do some logic
}
```

**Import** is required if you want `Contract A` to know how to handle `IERC20 contract` so you could call/delegate requests to it. It doesn't increase the size of `contract A`

On the other hand, **Inheritance** allows `Contract A` to literally inherit the logic and functionality from `IERC20`. Meaning that `A` inherits all functions from `IERC20` that have **public** or **internal** access modifiers. NOTE:(Not sure if Inheritance will increase the gas cost by much, as the contract you are inheriting in the first place also has to be deployed)

When writing SmartContracts you don't put entire logic into a single big contract. There are many reasons for it.

1.Smart Contracts have a limit to their size,24kb. Importing them allows you to circumvent this (You are not importing the entire contract, you are importing its location, its structure), which you need to call upon it latter.

2.The SmartContracts are generally **immutable** once deployed, so if you need to change anything, you will likely have to re-deploy the entire contract. So it's better to have the logic spread over multiple smaller contracts.

At least, that had been my experience.

Comment: I would correct your answer by saying that importing the contract does not bring with it its address, only its structure. The contract address you need to know and tell the other contract, as you did in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I should have explained that better. Will edit

Comment: I think the right language to use would be "implementing an interface" and "extending a contract".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not an obligation, it is a choice. It looks more systematic.